# Galois invariants and tensor products

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, etale-cohomology

Consider a number field $K$ and a finite Galois field extension $L/K$. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $K$ and consider the abelian group

$$E(L)\otimes L^{\times}.$$

Every element $g$ in $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ acts on it by $g(P\otimes \alpha) = g(P)\otimes g(\alpha)$ for $P\in E(L)$ and $\alpha\in L^{\times}$.

> **Problem 1.1** Do we have $(E(L)\otimes L^{\times})^{\text{Gal}(L/K)} = E(K)\otimes K^{\times}$?

(This question came up when others and I were trying our hand at the proof of the weak Mordell-Weil theorem. It has nothing to do with it, it just came up).

Also, what about $H^1$? That is

> **Problem 1.2** Is there an analog of Hilbert's Theorem 90 so that $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), E(L)\otimes L^{\times})=0$?

Now write $E(L)_{tf}$ for the maximal torsion-free quotient of $E(L)$.

> **Problem 2.1** Do we have $(E(L)_{tf}\otimes L^{\times})^{\text{Gal}(L/K)} = E(K)_{tf}\otimes K^{\times}$?

> **Problem 2.2** Do we have $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K),E(L)_{tf}\otimes L^{\times})=0$?

Comment: One should be careful with the statement - the natural map from $E(K)\otimes K^\times$ to $E(L)\otimes L^\times$ need not be injective due to torsion points.

Comment: I had initially intended to ask this question with the maximal-torsion free quotient of $E(L)$ instead of $E(L)$, but then forgot to write this. I have now modified the question to include this assumption. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I see. Examples like the one I wrote un my answer shoukd still exist with curves of positive rank. I will look for an example tomorrow.

Comment: Your tensor product kills the finite generation of $E(L)$ and the known cohomology of $L^{\times}$. I doubt that many interesting properties will be left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $E:y^2=x^3-3$ over $\mathbb Q$. Then $E(\mathbb Q)$ is trivial, hence so is $E(\mathbb Q)\otimes\mathbb Q^\times$. On the other hand, over $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ we have a point $P=(0,\sqrt{-3})\in E(L)$ which is mapped to its opposite by the complex conjugation. The same is true of $\sqrt{-3}\in L$, therefore $P\otimes\sqrt{-3}\in(E(L)\otimes L^{\times})^{\text{Gal}(L/K)}$, and we can check this element is nontrivial.

An analogous example for torsion-free parts is given by the point $P=(0,\sqrt{-2})\in E(L)$ for $E:y^2=x^3+x-2$ and $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$. $E(\mathbb Q)\cong\mathbb Z/2$ and $P$ is a point of infinite order, so $P\otimes\sqrt{-2}$ will be nontrivial in $E(L)_{tf}\otimes L^\times$.

I don't know any result for $H^1$ but I doubt there is anything as simple as Hilbert's 90. As a Galois representation, $E(L)$ can have quite nontrivial structure, even after tensoring with $\mathbb Q$, but I don't have an explicit counterexample at hand. (edit: actually see Chris Wuthrich's comment below though)

Comment: An example like that also works for $H^1$. This $M$ is $L^\times$ with the $G\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$-action twisted by the quadratic character. Now $H^1(G,M)$ computes to be $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}/N(L^{\times})$ as it is the kernel of $1-g$ on $L^\times$ quotient by the image of $-(1+g)$ where $g$ is the generator of $G$. -- All in all I would say this tensor product is a very strange object to consider.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, we need an element of $L$ whose complex conjugate is its multiplicative inverse rather than its additive inverse.